# sequential request in node js

Tags: node.js, async-await, httprequest

I'm learning to make an API in node js with express library
i have two things : product , order 
and each order has an address , one or more product and a total price which is based by price of products 
when i try to save an order i just pass the products IDs so in code i should get the products and sum their prices plus i want to show the products in the response so what i did was to put the ids in an array and i executed a foreach loop in array and in every loop i get the product and push it in an array .
the problem is that the response (actually every code after foreach loop) is executed before  i get the products,
i have searched about Async/Await and i tried to implement it but it didn't work 
my code is like this

```
function getproductpromis(options){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        http.get(options, resolt =>{
            let data ;
            resolt.on('data', d => {
                data +=d;
            })
            resolt.on('end', f =>{
                resolve (data);
            })
            resolt.on('error', e =>{
                reject(e);
                console.log(e);
            })
        });
    });
}

async function getproduct(element){
    let object;
    const options = {
        hostname:'localhost',
        port:5000,
        path:'/products/'+element,
        mathod:'GET'
    }

    const request_call = await getproductpromis(options);
    console.log('request_call');
    console.log(request_call);

    return request_call;


}

router.post('/',(req,res,next) => {
    let prod;
    console.log(req.body.products);
    const ids = req.body.products;
    let totalprice = 0;
    let objects =[];
    ids.forEach(element => {
        prod = getproduct(element);
        console.log('prod');
        console.log(prod);

        objects.push(prod);
    });
    res.status(200).json({
        objects
    });
}
```

and here is my log:

```
[ '5dab2706baab4b1e90dc30ff', '5dab2792f0662d4f54bbf1f1' ]
prod
Promise { <pending> }
prod
Promise { <pending> }
POST /orders 200 56.974 ms - 19
{ _id: 5dab2706baab4b1e90dc30ff,
  name: 'langero',
  quantity: 5,
  price: 1500,
  __v: 0 }
GET /products/5dab2706baab4b1e90dc30ff 200 208.973 ms - 114
request_call
undefined{"massage":"product found","product":{"ID":"5dab2706baab4b1e90dc30ff","name":"langero","quantity":5,"price":1500}}
{ _id: 5dab2792f0662d4f54bbf1f1,
  name: 'langer',
  quantity: 5,
  price: 1500,
  __v: 0 }
GET /products/5dab2792f0662d4f54bbf1f1 200 1172.254 ms - 113
request_call
undefined{"massage":"product found","product":{"ID":"5dab2792f0662d4f54bbf1f1","name":"langer","quantity":5,"price":1500}}
```

and response i get in postman 
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNU4Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `forEach` loop to `for...of` loop
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of]

Here is your updated `router.post` using `async/await` and `for...of` loop

```
router.post('/',async (req,res,next) => {
let prod;
console.log(req.body.products);
const ids = req.body.products;
let totalprice = 0;
let objects =[];
for (let element of ids) {
    prod = await getproduct(element);
    console.log('prod');
    console.log(prod);

    objects.push(prod);
}
res.status(200).json({
    objects
});
}
```

Comment: thank a lot . but could you explain why we changed foreach()

Comment: `forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike `map()` or `reduce()` it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable.

Check this example in their documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Note_regarding_usage_of_promise_or_async_function

Answer (score 0):

So you want to execute and an array of Promises, you're on the right track but may I point you in the direction of [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Here I marked your `router.post` callback as `async` so I can use `await`. I use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an array of promises that get passed to [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    const ids = req.body.products;

    const objects = await Promise.all(
        ids.map((id) => {
            return getproduct(id);
        })
    );

    res.status(200).json({
        objects
    });
});
```